# Tag a Repo from a Jenkins Workflow Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm currently trying to tag a repo from a Jenkins Workflow script. I've tried using a `sh` step but this runs into problems because of credentials not being set.

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://<repo>': Device not configured
```

Is there an existing step that can be used either to tag a repo or to get round the credentials problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by using the `withCredentials` step provided by the credentials binding plugin.

Its not great because it involved specifying it all in the URL but these values are masked in the console output.

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'MyID', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {

    sh("git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'")
    sh("git push https://${env.GIT_USERNAME}:${env.GIT_PASSWORD}@<REPO> --tags")
}
```

Comment: That is your best bet for now. [JENKINS-28335](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335) suggests a more convenient system.

Comment: I confirm that using [`sshagent(['git-credentials-id'])`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335?focusedCommentId=269000&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-269000) does work and is a bit easier. I used it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618449/how-to-checkout-ssh-remote-in-github-organization-and-use-ssh-credentials-in-jen)

Comment: The values may be masked in the console output, but anyone who has access to the machine can read the password from the process command-line. Let's hope we get a secure alternative soon!

Comment: If your password contains special characters, like the '@' for example, using it directly in the URL will not work. You can then set the password in the git-credentials like in Magnus Reftel's answer and pushing to the url like this: `GIT_ASKPASS=true git push http://${env.GIT_USERNAME}@some-git-server.com/some-project.git HEAD:master`.

Comment: Finally got his working.   My problem, was that I had other git operations inside the "withCredentials" block.   Like cloning, etc.  Putting the tag operations (tag, then push), inside another withCredentials block got it working.

Comment: The Answer by Magnus Reftler is much better. It supports passwords with any characters

Comment: This worked for me. And I solved the "involved specifying it all in the URL" mentioned by user3617723 to match my needs: Add this to environment section -> REPO = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo ${GIT_URL#*https://}').trim()

Answer (score 15):

Here's an alternative that does not require knowing the URL of the remote:

```
try {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'MyID', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
    sh("${git} config credential.username ${env.GIT_USERNAME}")
    sh("${git} config credential.helper '!echo password=\$GIT_PASSWORD; echo'")
    sh("GIT_ASKPASS=true ${git} push origin --tags")
  }
} finally {
    sh("${git} config --unset credential.username")
    sh("${git} config --unset credential.helper")
}
```

This works by having git read the username from the config, and let the credential helper supply the password only. The extra `echo` at the end is for making the command that git passes as an argument to the helper not end up on the same line as the password.

Answer (score 12):

If your git password contains special characters such as "%", ":", "@", or "/", passing `${env.GIT_PASSWORD}` as part of the git url ie `https://${env.GIT_USERNAME}:${env.GIT_PASSWORD}@<REPO>` without doing any encoding is likely to result in an `Invalid username or password` error.

To save any hassle using an inline credential.helper is a better way to go however the suggestion of `!echo password=\$GIT_PASSWORD; echo'` will result in a warning in your build logs `warning: invalid credential line: get` as the credential.helper is passed an argument to indicate the required operation (get,store,erase). In this case the credential helper is trying to interpret the `get` operation as a credential input. Valid inputs are protocol,host,path,username,password,url. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential#IOFMT

A better inline credential.helper would be `!f() { echo password=\$GIT_PASSWORD; }; f` This way the credential.helper operation `get` is ignored.

Full example:

```
try {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'MyID', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
    sh("${git} config credential.username ${env.GIT_USERNAME}")
    sh("${git} config credential.helper '!f() { echo password=\$GIT_PASSWORD; }; f'")
    sh("GIT_ASKPASS=true ${git} push origin --tags")    
  }
} finally {
    sh("${git} config --unset credential.username")
    sh("${git} config --unset credential.helper")
}
```

Comment: I've been using this solution so far and it works fine however we get intermittent issues and it seems to be a racing condition. I think adding `sleep 2` to `credential.helper` can help to fix the intermittent issue

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own [personal API token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) ([OAuth](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/)) and use it the same way as you would use your normal credentials (at: `/settings/tokens`). For example:

```
git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'
git push https://4UTHT0KEN@github.com/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried the solution of @user3617723 but from some reason something was missing. after a while I found my issue.
I have an upper job which responsible to pull the git repo and trigger the pipeline job with my workflow script which has different workspace:

```
//use the jenkins global credential id and create the env parametrs of GIT_PASSWORD and GIT_PASSWORD
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'cred-github', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {

//change directory to the work dir with the ".git" files and create tags
sh("cd ${MANAGER_WORKSPACE} ; git tag -a v-${props.'VERSION_NUMBER'} -m ${BUILD_URL}")

//get only the url after the https
giturl_push = GIT_URL.split("//")[1]

// change directory to the work dir with the ".git" files and push the tags to the repo
sh("cd ${MANAGER_WORKSPACE} ; git push https://${env.GIT_USERNAME}:${env.GIT_PASSWORD}@${giturl_push} --tags")




}
```