# Escape @ character in jenkins pipeline for git

Tags: git, jenkins

During our jenkins build we are attempting to push to git. Our password has recently changed, and now includes an @ symbol which gives the following error:

The advice seems to be to encode the password, but I am unable to figure out how to do this within our jenkins pipeline. How do I do this?
(I have also tried using the replace method to swap the @ symbol for %40, but that didn't work.)

```
def GIT_PASSWORD_R = GIT_PASSWORD.replace('@', '%40')
```

[Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

```
def GIT_PASSWORD_R = GIT_PASSWORD.toURL()       
git push -f https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD_R}@github.company.com/Product/subProd.git ${VERSION}-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: In what language do you expect the `def` to be parsed and where in your Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. Rather than encoding, another option that is working for me is to use a git credential helper. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038869/9463800

It sets up a git credential helper, does a git operation, and unsets the password in a finally block.

```
try {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'MyID', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
    sh("${git} config credential.username ${env.GIT_USERNAME}")
    sh("${git} config credential.helper '!echo password=\$GIT_PASSWORD; echo'")
    sh("GIT_ASKPASS=true ${git} push origin --tags")
  }
} finally {
    sh("${git} config --unset credential.username")
    sh("${git} config --unset credential.helper")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your answer according to hints at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer by quoting a bit more from the solution.