# Credentials binding in Jenkins causes issues

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, jenkins-groovy

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
    sh """
        git pull https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@github.domain.com
    """
}
```

The password string has an "@" symbol in it which causes the pull to not work. I'll explain how it's failing. Consider USERNAME = uname and PASSWORD = abcd@12345.
The above git pull command is construed as git pull https://xxxxx:xxxx@12345@github.domain.com. The @ causes the issue here.

Please suggest me what can I do to fix the problem.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57510599/598141)?

Comment: you can add an escape sequence character before `@` so that it will go smooth. try `${PASSWORD.replace('@','\\@')}`